# Advanced Forum permissions

Tags: 7, nodes

I have installed the [Advanced Forum](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) module for Drupal 7.10.

How can I set permissions for each forum I make? I want only administrators to have the "admin forum" permission, and not authenticated users.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Forum Access](http://drupal.org/project/forum_access) module works in Drupal 7, so I'll stick to this for now.

> This module changes your forum administration page to allow you to set forums private. You can control what user roles can view, edit, delete, and post to each forum. You can also give each forum a list of users who have administrative access on that forum (AKA moderators).
>
> This module requires the ACL module in order to function. The D7 version also requires the Chain Menu Access API module.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use another module to handle the permissions / access control. Look into [Taxonomy Access Control](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access), it has a d7 release. You might have to put each forum in its own taxonomy to enforce the permissions.

For example the Admin forum, add it to the "Admin only" taxonomy etc

Comment: This module doesn't seem to work. I deny forums from users by the can still view them.

Comment: Hmm works on my Drupal 6 site. Have you rebuilt permissions? Also I believe you need to deny access for roles you dont want rather than an opt in. (also check anonymous and authenticated default roles)

Comment: There seems to be issues in Drupal 7.